# How do you wait for an element in a dynamic web table?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I enter a value into a search box and then the web table starts loading its values based on the search. I do not go to a new page nor is the page itself 
 refreshing, meaning we are still on the same page. I want to wait for the values of the table to load without having to specifically say "wait X seconds", I want to fetch the elements as soon as the they have loaded in. How do I do this?

Ideally all the values in the table should be loaded but as of right now I am simply trying to wait for the first element in the table:

```
WebElement element =  (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"TableBox-react-component-2dd9bf99-63cb-4c78-9e0d-bed81526e7e5\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")));
```

This just ends up giving me an error after 10 seconds because it was unable to locate the element. This is with Selenium 2, chromedriver.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

HTML structure:

```
<head>...</head>
<body class="class-name" style>
  <div class="main">...</div>
  <script src="src-of-script"></script>
  <div class>
    <header class="page-header" uk-grid uk-panel uk-panel-box">...</header>
    <div class="teaching">
      <script type="application/json" class="js-react-on-rails-component" data-component-name="TableBox" data-dom-id="TableBox-react-component-*dynamic id*">
      <div id="TableBox-react-component-*dynamic id*>
        <div data-test="table-box" class="search-table-container">...</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain the problem comes from the locator you are using - it looks like generated from the browser (and those are **extremely** fragile), plus there's an `id` attribute with value that's almost certain to be dynamic. This would mean in every page load the actual locator would be different, and thus your wait will fail. Add the HTML source and we'll help you construct a more solid one.

Comment: @TodorMinakov Thank you for taking the time to respond to my issue. I think you are correct in what you are saying, when I reload the page, the table obtains a new ID. So, every time I run my program it will for the wrong table ID. The ID of the table does not change during pagination - which is nice. But, how do I go about targeting the table then? Is it possible that I could grab the id from the JavaScript attribute "data-dom-id" from the line above the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and catch with recursion function. Create a method with try and catch block where In try block, put Thread.sleet(seconds); and then call findElement. In catch call the function again. I had a problem with toast message which generate dynamically for specified time and it resolved with this approach

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but not sure if that would work. As I mentioned, I am using to use a WebDriverWait with 10 second timeout so I don't believe it has to do with me having to wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the id of the elements are dynamic - their suffixes change on every page load, you could try having a locator based on their constant parts. For that, the xpath function `contains()` is very handy.  This locator will select the very last `<div>` in your sample:

```
//div[@class="teaching"]/div[contains(@id, "TableBox-react-component")]/div[@data-test="table-box"]
```

The matched/reuturned element is going to be the `<div>` with the attribute data-test equal to "table-box" (the right-most in the expression), whose parent element is a `<div>` with id attribute having "TableBox-react-component" in its value. The `<div>` with the id must have a `<div>` parent whose class value is "teaching".
It might take a couple of trails and errors until you get the exact constant parts of the attributes, but that's the idea here.

Once certain about this part of the locator, you have to append the elements down to the `<table>` and `<td>` to it, to get to the actual target html element.